# How to select the first 3 rows containing a certain element within a list?

Tags: r, list, indexing, dataframe

In my current data.frame the column "Names" is a list of five names. I would like to select the first 3 rows where "Names" contains a certain name.

Current data.frame (DF):

```
Names        Hours  Gains   
A,B,C,D,E    12     8 
C,R,A,D,B    3      4
Z,W,D,B,A    6      3
T,R,H,Z,B    11     3 
J,A,C,B,D    8      0
R,E,T,C,Q    2      -2
B,C,D,J,A    1      -4
```

Desired Output for Names containing "C"

```
Names        Hours   Gains
A,B,C,D,E    12      8
C,R,A,D,B    3       4
J,A,C,B,D    8       0
```

I have tried:

```
library(data.table)
DF[Names == "C"][, .SD[C(1:3, .N)], by = Gains]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), you can use:

```
setDT(mydf)[grepl("C", Names), .SD[1:3]]
```

or:

```
setDT(mydf)[grepl("C", Names), head(.SD, 3)]
```

<sub>(if your data is not in a `data.table` yet, you have to convert your dataframe with `setDT()`)</sub>

both give:

> ```
>        Names Hours Gains
> 1: A,B,C,D,E    12     8
> 2: C,R,A,D,B     3     4
> 3: J,A,C,B,D     8     0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to combine `grepl` and `head`

Create a similar data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Names=c("A,B,C,D,E","C,R,A,D,B","Z,W,D,B,A","T,R,H,Z,B","J,A,C,B,D","R,E,T,C,Q","B,C,D,J,A"), Hours=c(12,3,6,11,8,2,1), Gains=c(8,4,3,3,0,-2,-4))
```

Then use grepl to identify rows with Names containing "C", then use head to select the first 3:

```
head(df[grepl(pattern = "C",x = df$Names),],3)

      Names Hours Gains
1 A,B,C,D,E    12     8
2 C,R,A,D,B     3     4
5 J,A,C,B,D     8     0
```

Comment: Or: `df[grepl("C", df$Names),][1:3,]`

Comment: The issue with this method is the actual data frame I am working with contains over 100 rows and is growing weekly. So creating a similar data frame does not seem like the most efficient approach.

Comment: I created the data frame just as an example for anyone who wants to reproduce it without typing it out themselves. If you already have the data frame then you don't need to create another one. It will work with however many rows you have.